# Set maximum width of Linear Layout

Tags: android, layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText 
    android:id="@+string/urlText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="Enter Url Here"/>
<Button
 android:id="@+string/go"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Go"/>
<WebView
 android:id="@+string/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

So with the above android layout, I am not able to make the editbox and button to be to the full width of the container. About 50 px from the left and the right are not filled.

Any sugestions

Comment: You might make use of the Hierarchy Viewer (in the tools directory of your sdk) to take a look, and see what is taking up that space.

Comment: Ok, I did that and it shows nothing, just that the width of the linear layout is 320 and the height is 480. But my device ( HTC Desire HD ) is 480x800.

Comment: The LinearLayout is the top level view in your view hierarchy?  Have you done any editing of the themes or styling, like adding padding, etc?

Comment: Yes it is the top level. Nothing, the above is the whole layout.xml. In the java source code it only loads the url in the edittextbox after the go button is clicked on the webviewer. That's all.

Comment: Wait actually the top level is PhoneWindow$DecorView.

Comment: Does the WebView take up the whole width?

Comment: Actually when a url is loaded the webview fills the entire screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I figured it out.

I went to the manifest file and added attributes for Supports Screens:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="false" 
    android:smallScreens="false" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
```

Thanks to Romain Guy for mentioning compability mode :)
Everything works now like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Is your app running in compatibility mode? From your description it sounds like it is, which would explain why it has HVGA dimensions (320x480).

Comment: I am targeting 2.2 android sdk, how to turn off compability mode ?